# Побудительное предложение — простое или сложное?

Tags: синтаксис, наклонение, наклонение-глагола

В побудительных предложениях сказуемые, выраженные глаголами в повелительном наклонении в одинаковой форме, рассматриваются как однородные сказуемые и предложение считается простым, или они рассматриваются как сказуемые разных частей и приложение считается сложным? Или есть нюансы и в разных предложениях по-разному?

Например:

*Так что проявляйте энтузиазм и будьте главной движущей силой в коллективе.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В школьной и довузовской практике считается, что в односоставном  предложении столько частей, сколько в нём сказуемых, за исключением случаев, когда в структуре сказуемого представлены однородные части.

Например:
*Я обиделся и не захотел ему отвечать* — простое двусоставное предложение с однородными сказуемыми.

*Мне стало обидно и не захотелось ему отвечать* — сложное предложение.

*Мне **стало грустно и одиноко*** — простое односоставное (безличное) предложение с однородными частями сказуемого.

*Так что проявляйте энтузиазм и будьте главной движущей силой в коллективе.* Это сложное предложение.

Простым предложением с однородными членами было бы предложение:

*Будьте **лидером и главной движущей силой** в коллективе*.

Т.е. **однородными сказуемыми считаются, если у них есть общая часть.**

Comment: Получается, что "Разделил и властвовал" - простое предложение, а "Разделяй и властвуй" — сложное? Можно ли обнаружить какую-то логику, стоящую за этим чисто формальным правилом?

Comment: @Людмила А  в вузовской практике считается как-то по-другому?

Comment: Разделил и властвовал - это вообще не предложение или неполное предложение(или парцеллированное). Он разделял и властвовал - простое с однородными сказуемыми, а Разделяй и властвуй - сложное, которое состоит из двух односоставных обобщённо-личных, деятель обобщён, это может быть кто  угодно, как одна личность, так и разные. Но и два определённо-личных тоже будут самостоятельными предложениями, потому что деятели здесь совсем не нужны, две независимых грамматических основы (если нет общей части составных глагольных сказуемых, тогда это будут однородные сказуемые)

Comment: Ксения, вузовская практика огромна, каждый учёный имеет свою точку зрения, но общепринято именно такое понимание, чтобы не противоречить определению : сложное предложение - предложение с несколькими грамматическими основами, а в односоставных простое предложение состоит из одного главного члена. Если сказуемые однородны, они должны относиться к одному подлежащему, а его здесь нет и быть не должно. В случае с составным глагольным сказуемым общая вспомогательная часть говорит об однородности сказуемых - будет это делать кто-то один.

Comment: _"Мне стало обидно и не захотелось ему отвечать" — сложное предложение._ А общий второстепенный член "мне" не делает это предложение простым с однородными сказуемыми согласно ответу @Sharon [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447974/tип-предложения-простое-или-сложносочинённое)?

Comment: Впрочем и вашему также.

Comment: Василий Ефименко, здесь сказуемые не однородны, потому что у них разные формы выражения - первое составное именное, второе - простое глагольное, вот стало обидно и грустно - однородны, а общий член у них "стало". Или "Не захотелось отвечать и улыбаться". Общей должна быть связка.

Answer (score 2):

*Так что проявляйте энтузиазм и будьте главной движущей силой в коллективе.*

Или: *Проявляйте энтузиазм и будьте главной движущей силой в коллективе.*

**Это сложное предложение, а не простое предложение с однородными сказуемыми.**

В такие предложения входят односоставные (определенно-личные или обобщенно-личные предложения).

Например: **Выходи, сударь, поскорее да обогрейся. Знай больше, а говори меньше.**

В большинстве случаев  **они однородны**, так как выражены одной формой глагола и подразумевают одного производителя действия, поэтому запятая перед союзами И, ДА=И не ставится.

**Общего элемента  в этом случае для однородности односоставных предложений не требуется.**

Comment: Получается, что "Разделил и властвовал" - простое предложение, а "Разделяй и властвуй" — сложное? Можно ли обнаружить какую-то логику, стоящую за этим чисто формальным правилом?

Comment: 1) Разделил и властвовал (я, ты, он). Предложение неполное двусоставное, субъект действия определяется по контексту. 2) Разделяй и властвуй. Для обоих  действий  предполагается собственный субъект действия (2-е лицо). И это не правило формальное, а формальная грамматика.

Comment: "Для обоих действий предполагается собственный субъект действия (2-е лицо)". Вот это мне и странно. Почему считается, что эти побудительные предложения побуждают  к действию  не один и тот же субъект?

Comment: По смыслу это один и тот же субъект, а формально каждый глагол самостоятельно указывает на определенное лицо, поэтому формально они не имеют общего субъекта..

Comment: То есть в неполном предложении подлежащее востанавливается и оказывается одним для обоих сказуемых, а в односоставном предложении подлежащего в принципе нет и быть не может, поэтому формально считается, что у каждого сказуемого свой собственный субъект действия. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Ну, это я так понимаю, исходя из того, что прочитала в книгах по грамматике, и пытаюсь вам пересказать. Возможно, есть и другой ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: А бывают однородные предложения? Это как? И разве запятая не ставится не из-за общей побудительной интонации?

Comment: Условное название. В правилах  говорится об одном производителе действия или об одинаковой форме глаголов и т.д., то есть о тех признаках, по которым односоставные предложения можно приравнять к однородным членам и запятую между ним не ставить.

Answer (score -1):

[Розенталь § 30](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133):

> 2. Перед союзами и, да (в значении и), или, либо запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения объединены каким-либо общим
>      элементом.

У вас есть общий элемент в предложении (союз *так что*), значит, запятая не ставится.

Вот еще информация:

> Оглянитесь вокруг, и увидите столько нового и интересного (Газ.) —
>   сложносочиненное предложение **(глагольные формы разных наклонений не
>   выступают в роли однородных членов простого предложения**).
>
> Запятая не ставится в односоставных неопределенно-личных
>   предложениях (если мыслится один и тот же производитель действия):
>   Стали искать черкесов во всех углах и, разумеется, ничего не нашли
>   (Л.); Подсудимых тоже куда-то выводили и только что ввели назад (Л.
>   Т.); Из церкви возвращались домой, ели пироги и снова ложились спать
>   до вечера (М. Г.);

Comment: Мой вопрос заключается не в постановке запятой, а в синтаксической характеристике сказуемых и предложения в целом. Ваш ответ не соответствует вопросу.

Comment: А как же иммунитет нового участника?  Можно сделать замечание, если вопрос не так понят, но нужно ли минусовать ответ?

Comment: Да я и не против. Вполне заслуженно.

Comment: Просто здесь правила поведения такие. Хорошо, когда на форуме  много отвечающих. А если по отношению к новому участнику сразу же проявить недружелюбие, то он может и не захотеть участвовать в работе.