# Tип предложения — простое или сложносочинённое?

Tags: синтаксис

***В ней тепло и сухо.***

1. Простое ли это предложение с основой ***"тепло и сухо"*** или сложносочинённое?
2. Найти ГРАММАТИЧЕСКУЮ ОСНОВУ.
3. Чем выражено сказуемое?

Мой ответ: **Безличное. Составное именное. Именная часть сказуемого выражена наречием.**

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос о квалификации таких предложений дискуссионный.

Пожалуй, наиболее трудно отграничить простые односоставные – безличные, инфинитивные и номинативные – предложения с однородными главными членами от сложносочиненных и бессоюзных сложных предложений, состоящих из соответствующих односоставных предикативных единиц.

Некоторые лингвисты считают, что простые односоставные предложения с однородными главными членами  «в принципе невозможны». В Грамматике-54 ничего не говорилось о том, могут ли главные члены односоставных предложений быть однородными. Не дает ответа на этот вопрос и Грамматика-70. Правда, здесь находим замечание:

> В сложном предложении *Сегодня тепло и солнечно, а вчера мела вьюга*
>   «обе предикативные единицы воспроизводят структурные схемы простого
>   предложения» [23, с. 652]. Из этого можно заключить, что предложение
>   Сегодня тепло и солнечно признается простым предложением с однородными
>   главными членами (предикативами).

У однородных главных членов односоставных предложений не может быть соподчиняющего компонента, поэтому показателем их функционального тождества **служит лишь зависимый компонент, наличие которого структурно необходимо для данного типа односоставных предложений.**

Для спрягаемо-глагольного класса безличных предложений таким компонентом обычно является сильноуправляемая словоформа с объектным (*корабль подбрасывает*) или субъектным (*снесло ветром*) значением.

Сопоставим простые **безличные односоставные предложения с однородными главными членами** и **сложные предложения, состоящие из безличных предикативных единиц.**

а) **Лодку** подхватило и понесло в темноту (Песков, II); Если **меня** ранит или убьет, он... окажется в оркестре дивизии, а то и армии (Бакл., IV); **Мне** печально и интересно (Шкл., I); **На улице** было мокро, грязно (Пан., XII); **Было** светло и весело (Песков, I); **Становилось** темно и удушливо (Бакл., III).

б) Холодно и неуютно (Песков, II); Ни неба не видно, ни земли не видно (Айтм., XXII); Ведь там нет дорог, там нет земли, там нет травы, там жизни нет (Айтм., XXIV); На него уже нельзя гаркнуть, нельзя трахнуть кулаком (Пан., III); Надо донести Парцванию до лодки, надо переправить его на ту сторону (Бакл., I); Не хотелось жить, не хотелось думать, не хотелось видеть ничего вокруг (Айтм., XXI).

https://studfiles.net/preview/4474410/page:32/

Валгина пишет:

> Главные члены безличных предложений однородны, если объединены общей
>   связкой: Было тихо, сумрачно и скучно (М. Г.). Такие предложения часто
>   имеют обстоятельственный или объектный распространитель: В саду было
>   тихо, прохладно (Ч.); Его знобило и лихорадило (Сераф.); В начале
>   улицы еще было ветрено, и дорога была заметена, но в середине деревни
>   стало тихо, тепло и весело (Л. Т.); Во рту было сухо и противно от
>   металлического вкуса (Ч.). В предложениях без связки лучше усматривать
>   части сложного: Пустынно и темно (Семушк.),

http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-029.htm

В нашем примере есть общая связка, т.е. общий второстепенный член:

***В ней*** тепло и сухо. Следовательно, это простое односоставное безличное с однородными сказуемыми.

Розенталь приводит пример односоставных номинативных.Здесь своя логика.

Для простых номинативных предложений показателем синтаксической однородности их главных членов может быть не только сильноуправляемая словоформа с объектным значением, слабоуправляемая или примыкающая словоформа с локальным значением, но и общее согласованное определение, а также связка. Приведем примеры п**ростых номинативных предложений с однородными главными членами** и **сложных предложений с номинативными предикативными единицами:**

*а) А вдруг такого потеряю? Тогда конец и горе **мне** (Тв., V); **В хуторе** сон и тишина (Бакл., III); **Непорядков** тьма и бездна (Тв., XV); Рев и предсмертный визг **Соболя** (Песков, VI); **Вот** и горка, и лесенка, ведущая к веденеевскому дому (Пан., XIV); **Вон** Николай Зюзин и Шура Пономарев – видел их в загсе (Песков, II); **Пустые** разговоры, обещания (Айтм., XVI).*

*б) Шум, грохот и пальба! (Носов, XI); Конец жизни, конец всему (Пан., XIII); Она могла смотреть часами: вот ее глаза, вот ее губы (Пан., X); Небо и степь. Голубое небо и желтая пшеница (Песков, I).*

Comment: "Главные члены безличных предложений однородны, если объединены общей связкой…" "В предложениях без связки лучше усматривать части сложного". А у нас нет связки. При этом про общий распространитель Валгина просто говорит, что часто он присутствует, но это не обязательное условие. Также вы пишите: "В нашем примере есть общая связка, т.е. общий второстепенный член". Связка = второстепенный член?

Comment: В ней тепло и сухо - связка нулевая "есть/было/будет" + распространитель  "в ней". "Т.е." , конечно, ошибочно, каждое само по себе.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется естественным считать "тепло и сухо" однородными сказуемыми, но ничто не мешает объявить это ССП, состоящим из двух односоставных безличных предложений. Вопрос чисто академический, на результат не влияет.

Comment: Согласна с М_Г, вопрос действительно академический и до сих пор дискуссионный, а Розенталь приводит пример назывных предложений, которые действительно  входят в состав ССП, но есть другие примеры, где назывные тоже могут объединяться в простое с однородными членами, если предикативы занимают одно синтаксическое место, а это случается при наличии общего члена.

Comment: Для автора вопроса его академический характер, наверное, не очень интересен. Ему надо знать правильный и однозначный, а не дискуссионный. ответ. Ответ, который соответствует академическим источникам, а не нашему личному мнению.

Comment: А Вы приведите правильный ответ, не дискуссионный, со ссылкой на авторитетный источник, если Валгина для Вас не авторитет, вот  студентов до сих пор по её учебникам учат. А у Розенталя что-то нет разграничения простых односоставных с однородными членами  и ССП, состоящих из односоставных, у него только знаки препинания

Answer (score 0):

Это мой ответ на вопрос:

**В ней тепло и сухо.**

1) Это простое односоставное безличное предложение с однородными сказуемыми.

2) Грамматическая основа: ***тепло и сухо***.

3) Сказуемое составное именное, связка отсутствует, именная часть выражена двумя однородными предикативными наречиями (словами категории состояния), связанными союзом И.

**Дополнительная информация:** Сказуемые имеют общий распространитель ***в ней*** (что позволяет считать данное предложение простым с однородными сказуемыми, а не сложным предложением).

**Примечание:**

Это именно ответ на вопрос, заданный его автором. Другие вопросы, а также часть комментариев я считаю **несоответствующими теме вопроса и, соответственно,  правилам форума.**

В чем несоответствие?

**Вместо конкретного ответа  (ученику!) предлагается неопределенная дискуссия.**

Свой первый ответ я удаляю, так как у меня нет желания в этой дискуссии участвовать, а мое мнение оказалось неинтересным для общества, никем не не одобренным  и поэтому ненужным.

**Надеюсь на ваше понимание.**

В дальнейшем я постараюсь работать строго **в обозначенном формате:** четкий ответ без каких-либо отступлений и комментарии только по содержанию вопроса.

**Другим участникам я также предлагаю по возможности соблюдать правила форума.**