# Влияние интонации на пунктуацию

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, авторская-пунктуация, интонация

1. *Как вы оцениваете организацию первого дня соревнований[,] и как организацию второго?*

Вопросительная интонация вроде бы объединяет первую часть и вторую, неполную, — запятая не нужна; но интонационно между частями всё же есть пауза.

2. *Поэтому на последнем слайде обязательно размещайте ссылку на свой сайт и страницы в соцсетях[,] и потом, когда выступление будет подходить к концу, долго держите эту информацию на экране.*

Здесь однородные односоставные (побудительные) предложения, выраженные глаголами в одинаковой форме, однако есть смысловая пауза: события происходят в разное время.

**Вопрос**. Как расставить знаки в вышеприведённых предложениях? И вообще, по какому принципу можно/разрешается добавлять собственные, интонационные, авторские запятые? Именно запятые — про авторское тире всё понятно: лепи, куда душе угодно.

Comment: 1) Не доверяйте паузам, они Вас могут обмануть. Практически пауза присутствует в каждом простом предложении, где нет запятых, но она всего лишь обозначает перелом интонации.  2) Русская пунктуация основана на трех принципах (смысловом, грамматическом, интонационном), но пользоваться ими надо правильно. 3) Я думаю, что нет интонационных запятых, не связанных с грамматикой. К примеру, мы можем по желанию обособлять или не обособлять оборот, но при этом  меняем  грамматику и структуру  предложения, а также вносим в него новые смысловые оттенки. Вот так взаимодействуют три принципа интонации.

Comment: Общая схема: семантика - грамматика+ структура - интонация + пунктуация. Вы говорите: смысловая пауза. Но нужно по смыслу выбрать грамматику и структуру предложения, в котором можно по правилам поставить запятую. В то же время эта запятая будет соответствовать вашей смысловой паузе. Также прочитайте мой ответ к вопросу https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447974/tип-предложения-простое-или-сложносочинённое Там  рассматривается тема односоставных предложений. Если сказуемые не связаны тесно друг с другом (нет спаянности), то мы можем считать  такое предложение сложным и поставить запятую.

Comment: @Sharon 1) Согласен с тем, что в каждом простом предложении есть перелом интонации, ведь в нём всегда есть слово, на котором стоит логическое ударение. В месте ударения идёт повышение тона голоса с последующим его понижением. Но пауза там откуда? 2) Я правильно понимаю, что в обоих моих предложениях вы бы запятую (которая в квадратных скобках) не ставили?

Comment: Я позже отвечу на Ваши вопросы, пока только скажу, что логическое ударение в простом неосложненном предложении есть не всегда (оно обычно связано с инверсией), но в нем обычно всегда есть два тонических ударения (две фразы с восходящей и нисходящей интонацией).

Comment: @Sharon Под логическим ударением я имел в виду не особое выделение, как при инверсии, а наибольшее тоническое ударение в предложении, которое определяет смысл: «ОтЕц идёт», «Отец идЁт». Действительно, обычно в простом предложении есть два тонических ударения, но одно из них всегда сильнее (по ошибке я его называл логическим). И да, появляется две фразы. Но между этими ними нет паузы, запятую поставить рука не тянется. Если неправ, приведите пример.

Comment: Русское ударение имеет три характеристики: силовую, временную и тоническую. Логическое фразовое ударение - это тоническое ударение + силовое (динамическое) ударение. Простое предложение обычно состоит из двух фраз с одинаковым тоническим ударением в конце каждой фразы. Логическое ударение в Ваших примерах - это дополнительное силовое ударение (здесь нет инверсии).  Но при инверсии логическое выделение не требует  значительного усиления голоса, смещенное тоническое ударение и так выделяет нужное слово.

Comment: @Sharon Хорошо, я с вами согласен. Но разве между двумя фразами в простом предложении бывает пауза, причём такая, что можно по ошибке поставить запятую?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Как вы оцениваете организацию пЕрвого дня соревнований //и как (вы оцениваете) организацию вторОго?**

Это двусоставные предложения, второе предложение неполное.

По правилам при наличии общей вопросительной интонации и союза И **запятая не ставится.** Но это скорее грамматическое правило, потому что **реальная интонационная картина выглядит несколько сложнее,** и пауза там действительно есть.

Мы знаем, что вопросительная интонация — это повышение тона в конце предложения (в повествовательных предложениях тон понижается).

Фактически мы повышаем тон (ставим тоническое ударение) **дважды,** причем **на тех словах, которые хотим выделить.** В этом случае  тон в середине предложения должен быть понижен, и это понижение логично сделать в конце первого предложения, что мы и ощущаем как паузу.

2) **Поэтому на последнем слайде обязательно *размещайте* ссылку на свой сайт и страницы в соцсетях  и потом, когда выступление будет подходить к концу, долго *держите* эту информацию на экране.**

Предложения в составе ССП односоставные определенно-личные, но это не побудительные предложения (в них нет побудительной интонации, частицы пусть и т.д.) [https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/1094/побудительное](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/1094/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5)

**Фактически ни у Розенталя, ни в ПАС этот вид односоставных предложений не рассматриваются,** но при анализе других односоставных предложений говорится о том, что отсутствие запятой связана **с грамматической и семантической однородностью** (это тот самый **фактор спаянности** сказуемых, который не так давно обсуждался). Тогда будем говорить об этом факторе.

Грамматическая форма одинаковая, но много других факторов, препятствующих однородности: **некомпактное расположение, индивидуальные распространители, в том числе временное наречие и даже целое придаточное предложение.**

С другой стороны, всё перевешивает общее наречие **поэтому** в препозиции, оно объединяет эти два предложения. Соответственно,  запятая по общему правилу (для односоставных и двусоставных предложений) **не ставится.**

Отсутствие запятой влияет и на и интонацию предложения. **Паузы,** соответствующей сложному предложению, **там нет,** хотя небольшая **произносительная** пауза может присутствовать.

Примечание

Цитата: Именно запятые — про авторское тире всё понятно: **лепи, куда душе угодно.**

**Вот уж нет, не получится лепить.** Тире обозначает не только паузу, оно меняет расстановку ударений в предложении. При этом и само тире может быть разным — разделительным или присоединительным. Всё это надо учитывать и объяснять как грамматику, так и семантику.

В этом смысле интересны две недавние темы, где обсуждалось **интонационное тире.**

[Интонационное тире *](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448148/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5/448149#448149)

[Нужно ли тире в предложении: "Готов ответить на интересующие вас вопросы (–) в рабочем порядке после заседания"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448086/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%80/448116?noredirect=1#comment458636_448116)

Comment: 1) Так в первом предложении запятая всё-таки не ставится вопреки интонации — наличию паузы между предложениями? 2) По-моему, во втором предложении выражение просьбы, призыва. И сказуемое в форме повелительного наклонения разве само по себе не подразумевает побудительную интонацию?

Comment: 1) Не ставится. Мы не обозначаем каждую паузу запятой, а здесь пауза вынужденная, произносительная. Важно на письме показать  вопросительный характер обоих предложений, а при наличии запятой  вопросительный знак может относиться только ко второму предложению. 2) Побудительная интонация  - это повелительное наклонение +  восклицание. Не каждая повелительное наклонение является призывом.

Comment: _Точка ставится в конце **побудительного предложения**, если оно произносится без восклицания: Вам бы полечиться. (М. Г.); Позвольте мне прочесть в другой раз. (Бл.); Ты меня не учи. (Добров.)_ (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=87#pp87)

Comment: Терминология может быть разной, например: По интонации различаем восклицательные и невосклицательные предложения. По цели высказывания - предложения повествовательные, вопросительные и побудительные предложения.  А где в это определении вопросительная интонация?