# Нужно ли тире в предложении: "Готов ответить на интересующие вас вопросы (–) в рабочем порядке после заседания"?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

> Готов ответить на интересующие вас вопросы – в рабочем порядке после заседания.

Нужно ли тире?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом предложении ставить тире нежелательно:

**Готов ответить на интересующие вас вопрОсы //в рабочем порядке после заседАния.**

Наличие присоединительного оборота здесь **семантически не оправдано,** обстоятельство входит в основное сообщение на тему, когда можно задавать вопросы.

Если автор хочет его обособить, то надо изменить структуру или грамматику предложения, например:

(1) Готов ответить на интересующие вас вопросы **позже –  в рабочем порядке после заседания.**  Здесь присоединительная конструкция будет иметь значение **пояснения**.

(2) Готов ответить на интересующие вас вопрОсы, **но только в рабочем порядке после заседАния.**

Comment: По контексту 1-й вариант вполне подходит (с добавкой слова позже).

Answer (score 3):

На вопрос "Нужно ли тире?" отвечаем: не нужно.

Но на вопрос о его допустимости я бы ответил положительно. Если рассматривать слова "в рабочем порядке после заседания" как дополнительную, уточняющую информацию, то тире можно поставить, и, сооответственно, появится пауза при чтении.

Comment: Вы думаете, что паузу можно сделать в любом месте любого предложения?

Comment: @Sharon Я это предложение с паузой (и пониxением тона) попробовал произнести — нормально звучит.

Comment: Похоже: *И щуку бросили – в реку.*

Comment: Перед присоединительным тире делается понижения тона. Картина тогда складывается такая.  Автор вроде бы закончил предложение, все ему поверили, были готовы задать эти вопросы, но после выдержанной ораторской паузы им добавили другую информацию.

Comment: Ну да, я же говорю, что здесь присутствует элемент неожиданности. В басне это авторский художественный прием, а в реальности похоже на необоснованный "обман" публики.

Comment: @Sharon, Просто живая речь, пауза вместо того, чтобы сказать "но".

Comment: Здесь еще контекст нужно учитывать, коммуникативную ситуацию. Вот кто-то тянет руку вовремя заседания: "Можно вопрос?" Ему отвечают: Готов ответить на интересующие вас вопросы. Вопрос уже начали задавать, но  лектор его останавливает последующим замечанием. А нельзя ли в одной фразе сразу сказать, когда можно задавать вопросы. Вывод: можно поставить тире, но ЗАЧЕМ это надо делать?

Comment: @Sharon, Для передачи реальной устной речи, по-моему.

Comment: Тогда ЗАЧЕМ в реальной устной речи делать паузу?

Comment: @Sharon, Вопрос ЗАЧЕМ здесь неуместен. Вы хотите сказать, что так не говорят в реальной жизни?

Comment: Неуместен? Вас спросили: нужно ставить тире/делать паузу? А Вы отвечаете, что без разницы, можно ставить, а можно нет. Если Вы не видите смысловых различий эти двух вариантов, то, наверное,  Вы правы. Но это только в том случае, если Вы их не видите. Вот и Крылов зачем-то тире поставил. Так, авторские причуды.

Comment: @Sharon, Я вижу разницу, но не вижу контекста,  поэтому оставляю автору  право выбора.

Comment: А я не представляю такого контекста, при котором здесь надо делать паузу и обозначать её тире. Поэтому я пишу автору: тире ЖЕЛАТЕЛЬНО не ставить.  В любом случае это интонационное тире, которое надо как-то объяснять.