# Присоединительное тире, обусловленное задумкой автора

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире, авторская-пунктуация

Уже велось обсуждение о возможности произвольного  отделения автором второстепенного члена в присоединительную конструкцию (см. [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448086/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%80/448116?noredirect=1#comment458636_448116)). Участник сообщества **Sharon** в своём ответе сказала, что именно в той ситуации, которую описывает предложение в указанном вопросе, наличие присоединительного оборота семантически не оправдано, поскольку второстепенный член — обстоятельство входит в основную мысль предложения.

А что насчёт такой ситуации?

*В ближайший год-два должность своего руководителя вы точно не займёте — легальным способом.*

В предложении применён юмор с использованием присоединительной конструкции. Делается пауза, которая добавляет элемент неожиданности. Однако обстоятельство "легальным способом" синтаксически может входить и в основную мысль высказывания без присоединения. Может ли автор в данном случае самостоятельно отделить обстоятельство и сделать присоединение? Или юмористическая задумка также не может оправдать присоединительный оборот?

Comment: _Василий Ефименко: Sharon в своём ответе сказала, что... второстепенный член — обстоятельство входит в основную мысль предложения._ === Знать, какую **основную мысль** и какую интонацию нужно донести до читателя, может только автор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ **исправлен и дополнен** с учетом **ответа slava1947**

Задумка автора осуществляется **через грамматическую структуру предложения.**

**Вариант 1**.  В ближайший год-два //должность своего руководителя ***легальным способом*** //вы точно не займёте.

Порядок слов определяется актуальным членением предложения: детерминант – тема – рема.В ближайший год–два //должность своего руководителя ***легальным способом*** //вы точно не займёте.

Предложение построено, структура определена. Но структура этого предложения допускает и **вставочное обособление** без перестройки, так как ***легальным способом*** находится на границе тема – рема: В ближайший год-два должность своего руководителя – ***легальным способом*** – //вы точно не займёте (См. ответ slava1947).

**Вариант 2.** Теперь нам захотелось сделать   ***легальным способом*** присоединительной конструкцией. Для этого **перестраиваем** структуру предложения:

Должность своего руководителя в ближайший год-два // вы точно не займёте — ***легальным способом***.

Предложение без обособленного оборота имеет законченный смысл и структуру, в конце его делается пауза,  после чего добавляется присоединительный оборот.

Comment: Sharon, ну, коли взяли у меня вариант и вписали его в своё сообщение, может...

Comment: Авторские права? Сейчас впишу.  Просто в этом варианте нет неожиданного присоединения, о котором говорил автор вопроса. Здесь выделение, подчеркивание, но только не неожиданность. Я бы не стала его брать, но надо было указать два варианта без перестройки, иначе это было бы незаконченное объяснение, не совсем понятное для автора вопроса.  Извините, я не подумала об авторстве.

Comment: _Sharon: Авторские права? Сейчас впишу. Просто в этом варианте нет неожиданного присоединения, о котором говорил автор вопроса. Здесь выделение, подчеркивание, но только не неожиданность. Я бы не стала его брать, но надо было указать два варианта без перестройки, иначе это было бы незаконченное объяснение_.  === Угу... незаконченное... Вы, видимо, уже забыли своё данное ранее, а сейчас убранное **объяснение**:

_"Здесь обособление легальным способом нежелательно (предложение будет выглядеть неестественным и неудобным для прочтения).**_

Comment: Не забыла, конечно, просто ваш вариант нарушил  логику моего объяснения (был не очень кстати), так как встречаются варианты с двойным толкованием без перестройки (а я его упустила). Вот и пришлось его упомянуть. А что Вы теперь хотите, как мне обозначить, что он Ваш? Вы скажите,  я поправлю ответ.

Comment: Да бог с вами… Делайте что хотите. Коснусь немного только вот этого: тема, рема… Зачем всё это здесь упоминать?  Вы написали (в последней версии Вашего ответа): "Но структура этого предложения допускает и вставочное обособление без перестройки, **так как _легальным способом_ находится на границе тема – рема…**"  Ну при чём здесь эта граница? А если б "легальным способом" находилось не не упомянутой Вами границе, а в каком-то ином месте,  — что, употребление вставки стало бы невозможным? Да попробуйте _легальным способом_ убрать с границы, поместите его хотя бы после местоимения "вы"...

Comment: Тема и рема - это деление предложения на фразы. Вставку надо делать в удобном месте, чтобы предложение нормально читалось. В частности, после "вы" ее неудобно размещать. Местоимение придется относить к предыдущей фразе, куда оно плохо вписывается. Но в одном Вы, наверное, правы - меня здесь мало кто понимает, поэтому и говорить незачем. Нет аудитории, которой это было бы интересно.Как говорится, есть над чем подумать, особенно сегодня.

Comment: Вам ни о чём задумываться не стоит: продолжайте давать такие же развёрнутые ответы со всеми нюансам, как вы это делаете сейчас. Если некоторые вас не понимают (зачастую я тоже), это даёт им повод разобраться в новых для себя, более глубоких темах русского языка.

Comment: Спасибо! Если бы Вы знали, как мне сейчас нужна поддержка, а то я уже думаю,  не уйти ли с сайта вообще.

Comment: В частности, актуальное членение и интонация — это вещи, которые играют важнейшую роль в передаче в предложении нужного автору смысла. Так что эти темы стоит поднимать, если есть такая необходимость. А не думать, что отвечающий просто умничает.

Comment: Если сравнить Ваш **Вариант 2** с вариантом из моего вопроса, то видим: Вы лишь поменяли местами дополнение и обстоятельство. Разве без этой перестройки предложение не имеет такого же законченного смысла и структуры без обособленного оборота?

Comment: Сравним: В ближайший год-два  должность своего руководителя //вы точно не займёте. (2) Должность своего руководителя в ближайший год-два // вы точно не займёте.  Перестройка здесь чисто  интонационная, а не смысловая.  Объем предложения уменьшился, поэтому появилась возможность не отделять паузой обстоятельство, а включить его в первую фразу. Но сделать это надо так, чтобы предложение гладко читалось. Причитайте  варианты,  и Вы увидите, что структура второго читается проще. Как лучше расположить смысловые части - этот вопрос решается для каждого предложения, т.е. перестановка необязательна.

Comment: А вы хороший "ученик", схватываете на лету.  Я так  давно уже рассказываю здесь про интонацию, но единственный успех - это то, что люди перестали негативно воспринимать это слово. Теперь иногда они и сами  его употребляют.

Answer (score 1):

Вы же должны знать, что авторское тире может ставиться практически где угодно. Юмористическая задумка ни при чём – тире вполне оправдано и без нее, если автор так захотел.

Comment: Я думал также. Но по вполне аргументированному ответу **Sharon** на вопрос, на который я сослался, оказывается, нужны определённые семантические и грамматические условия, которые оправдают использование присоединительного оборота. И если этих в условий нет, одного лишь «автор так захотел» будет недостаточно для обоснования постановки тире.

Comment: Ну да, у Горького -- непревзойденного почитателя тире -- много ли "обоснований"?

Answer (score 1):

> Может ли автор в данном случае... сделать присоединение?

Может.

Но лучше предложение несколько перестроить. Причём я выбрал бы вариант, про который Sharon в своём ответе в этой теме написала:

> Здесь обособление *легальным способом* нежелательно (предложение будет выглядеть неестественным и неудобным для прочтения).

Ну а я бы обособил. И на мой взгляд – это самый удобный для произнесения и прочтения вариант:

*В ближайший год-два должность своего руководителя – **легальным способом!** – вы точно не займёте.*

(Восклицательный знак можно не ставить.)

**P. S.**

И ещё... Вместо "ближайший", имхо, лучше было бы употребить форму мн. ч. (такая форма в сочетании с "год-два" встречается чаще):

***В ближайшие** год-два...*

Comment: Я руководствуюсь правилом, что дефис в данном случае заменяет союз "или", то есть вариант без дефиса выглядит так: "В ближайший год или два…" Интересно, те, кто использует форму множественного числа, чем это мотивируют?

Comment: Чем? Своим чувством языка.