# Интонационное тире (2)

Tags: синтаксис, авторская-пунктуация, интонация

В справочниках Валгины и Розенталя в разделе "Интонационное тире" есть такие примеры.

Дальше шли пешеходы с мешками, с узлами;

Дальше шли пешеходы - с мешками, с узлами.

Н.С Валгина разницу в примерах объясняет так.

Как будто бы знак поставлен на интонационном основании - он стоит на месте паузы. Но это лишь внешняя причина. На самом деле интонация подчинена заданному смыслу, заданному членению предложения. В первом варианте предложения (без знака и, следовательно, паузы) словоформы **с мешками, с узлами** мыслятся как **определения** при имени существительном **пешеходы**, и смысл всего предложения дает возможность предположить, **что вначале шли пешеходы и без мешков и без узлов.** Во втором варианте предложения (с логическим ударением на слове пешеходы) смысл другой: **вначале шли не пешеходы.**

Но мне не ясен смысл объяснения. В тексте написано про мешки и узлы,  и вдруг они оказались без мешков и узлов. А во втором предложении, как мне кажется, логическое ударение падает на мешки и узлы. И как понять, что сперва шли не пешеходы? Кто тогда?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё правильно объяснено.

(1) Дальше шли пешеходы (какие?)  **с мешкАми, с узлАми;**

Необособленное определение ***с мешками, с узлами*** обозначает **отличительный признак пешеходов**, вот и получается, что сначала шли другие пешеходы (возможно, без вещей).

(2) ДАльше шли пешехОды ― **с мешкАми, с узлАми.**

Обособленное определение ***с мешками, с узлами*** обозначает **дополнительную информацию** о пешеходах, главное ― это то, что шли именно пешеходы. На этом содержание основной части предложения заканчивается. Соответственное, перед ними могли ехать, например, машины.

Обособленное определение всегда имеет собственное ударение (не логическое, а просто тоническое)